# Scroll to bottom of listview from base adapter

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` and inside that `ListView` I have an `ImageButton`. When the user clicks that ImageButton a new item is inflated but every time I add a new item I have to scroll down to see the added item. I need help to get that scroll moving to the last item automatically after it has been added.

Note that My `ImageButton` is in a different layout (but it's part of the listview) and the same layout has a `LinearLayout` which acts as a parent view to my inflated child views.

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutOther"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_5sdp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/objectiveOtherCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Other Objectives"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addOtherObjectiveTextBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/objectiveOtherCheckBox"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button2"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"/>
//parent layout
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/otherObjLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/objectiveOtherCheckBox"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code inside my base adapter which inflates the child view. In this function, I want to scroll the `ListView` to bottom after adding an item.

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addOtherObjectiveTextBox);
                imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked123", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(v.getContext());
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.otherobjectivedialog);

                        final EditText enterObjET = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.enterObjEditText);
                        Button closeEnterObjBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.closeEnterObjDialog);
                        Button objConfirmBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.enterObjConfirmBtn);

                        closeEnterObjBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

                        objConfirmBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(final View v) {
                                final String enteredObj = enterObjET.getText().toString();
                                if(enteredObj.equals("")){
                                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Please write a objective", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }else {

                                    final View editChildView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.other_objective_edittext, null);
                                    editParentLL.addView(editChildView);

                                    final TextView tvOO = editChildView.findViewById(R.id.otherobjTextView);
                                    ImageView ivOOEdit = editChildView.findViewById(R.id.otherobjEdit);
                                    ImageView ivOODelete = editChildView.findViewById(R.id.otherobjDelete);
                                    tvOO.setText(enteredObj);
                                    ivOODelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view) {
                                            int posValue2 = editParentLL.indexOfChild(editChildView);
                                            editParentLL.removeView(editChildView);
                                            otherObjList.remove(posValue2);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    ivOOEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view) {
                                            int editPosValue = editParentLL.indexOfChild(editChildView);
                                            final Dialog dialog2 = new Dialog(con);
                                            dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.otherobjectivedialog);

                                            final EditText enterObjET2 = (EditText) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.enterObjEditText);
                                            Button closeEnterObjBtn2 = (Button) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.closeEnterObjDialog);
                                            Button objConfirmBtn2 = (Button) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.enterObjConfirmBtn);
                                            String otherObjectiveTextToEdit = otherObjList.get(editPosValue);
                                            enterObjET2.setText(otherObjectiveTextToEdit);

                                            closeEnterObjBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    dialog2.dismiss();
                                                }
                                            });
                                            objConfirmBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                                    int editPosValue2 = editParentLL.indexOfChild(editChildView);
                                                    final String enteredObj2 = enterObjET2.getText().toString();
                                                    if(enteredObj2.equals("")){
                                                        Toast.makeText(con, "Please write a objective", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    }else {
                                                        dialog2.dismiss();
                                                        tvOO.setText(enteredObj2);
                                                        otherObjList.put(editPosValue2, enteredObj2);

                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                            dialog2.show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                    //objectiveOtherET.setText(objectiveOtherET.getText().toString()+ " \n" + enteredObj);
                                    //Log.i("POS", "onClick: "+editParentLL.indexOfChild(editChildView));
                                    otherObjList.put(oo, enteredObj);
                                    oo++;
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        dialog.show();

/*                            LinearLayout linearLayoutNew = new LinearLayout(con);
                            linearLayoutNew.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                            et = new EditText(con);
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            et.setLayoutParams(p);
                            et.setHint("Set some objective");
                            linearLayoutNew.addView(et);
                            ll.addView(linearLayoutNew);*/
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

After notifying list for changes you need to call scroll on `ListView`.

```
list_View.smoothScrollToPosition(list_View.getChildCount());
```

**Or** if calling from non Ui thread.

```
list_View.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                list_View.smoothScrollToPosition(list_View.getChildCount());
            }
        });
```

Comment: how can I access ListView from my base adapter?

Comment: Thats just one method away. create a public method in activity and call it .

Comment: I passed the listview to my constructor in my base adapter and then I used your code but it didn't work.

Comment: Any suggestions?